# Best way to prevent SQL injections in Joomla 3

Tags: php, sql, joomla, code-injection

I'm working to create a function that call a field in joomla database. 
Is that a good usage to prevent sql injection?

```
// Get std objects
if (strlen($urlparams)<5) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('params');
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__template_styles'));
    $query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote($urlparams));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row  = $db->loadResult();
}
else {
    echo 'Something is going worng.';
}
```

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Well, judging by your question and the only answer posted so far - it appears the best way to prevent SQL injections in Joomla is not to use Joomla. It's almost 2015. and there are still "smart" devs who won't expose PDO in a proper manner to people using their software ... good luck with your website, I sincerely hope you never get hacked.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion but i've used joomla different times and i don't have any type of problems. I think that joomla is vulnerable when people use 3rd party extensions. 

I've developed more than 50 websites with joomla and all work fine.

Comment: Well, you can always kindly ask some of "Anonymous" people to take a look at one of your 50 joomla websites and then you can see whether you have any types of problems or not. What I'm suggesting is that Joomla should expose proper PDO interface instead of some half-baked "JDatabase" (gotta laugh at that name). You're simply doing more work than you're supposed to, that's all. Plus it doesn't look safe whatsoever, quoting input manually...

Comment: @N.B. - There is nothing wrong with using Joomla's itself as they use various methods to prevent attacks. The problem is, as the OP mentioned in the comment above, it 3rd party extensions. As for the JDatabase class you feel seems to be a joke, the reason the way database queries are written like this is because it supports **more** than just PDO, therefore if one day, should you ever decide to move from MySQL to PDO, you won't need to update every single query known to Joomla. If you feel it is not safe, It would be nice if you could note what exactly if not safe and provide a valid example.

Comment: @Lodder - the move from one RDBMS (I assume you were talking about that) to another isn't as easy as "Oh I will use this pseudo DBAL and everything will now work on Mongo". Anyone who has done it has experienced it. The JDatabase is a joke. The mere fact you have to "clean" the input manually insinuates it. The idea behind it is good - have an ORM that doesn't force you to rewrite queries if something should happen. But we have excellent, proven and tested ORMs like Doctrine and Eloquent. I understand you guys like and use Joomla, it's just that it's a crap software and that's a fact.

Comment: It depends on how you look at things. You say "crap", and yes there are some things with Joomla and the decisions made that strike me as simply stupid, however for a user that does not have time or maybe experience to use a delve into the likes of Doctrine, for some projects, it would be a good choice. As a standalone CMS, it **is** secure but again, does have it's downsides. But yes, in regards to having to manually escape fields and values, this is something I too wonder why should be done. Anyway, Joomla is only progressing as much as it is contributed to. It can only get better (hopefully)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You current method is perfectly fine as it uses the most up to date Joomla coding standards.

The only thing I would do it use `quoteName()` in your `select` clause which is used to escape field names. So you would end up with the following:

```
$query->select($db->quoteName('params'));
```

If you are ever in doubt, have a look at Joomla's:

- [Secure Coding Guidelines](http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines) and
- [Documentation for Accessing the Database](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)